# How to execute ".exe" from R shell(cmd) as admin?

Tags: r, shell, admin

I need to execute an ".exe" File from R through the shell as administrator. I have the admin rights for certain operations such as executing the particular ".exe" file.
When I use shell(cmd), R tells me "Permission denied".
Yet, I want to include the running of the ".exe" into my R code.
Do you have any suggestions?

Is there a way to pass on an argument such as "runas" as option to "shell(cmd)"?

I do not work on a private workstation but on a licenced one from my workplace with certain restrictions.

- When I open the terminal independently from R as admin and execute the ".exe", it works fine.
- I openned R as admin and run the command, no success

Comment: What do your R commands actually look like? And you are running just R, not RStudio or anything? So you're sure you ran R as admin? That should inherit the same permissions I would think. If you run `shell("whoami")` to you get the admin username back? Or something else?

Comment: The command reads: `shell(paste0(gap50path, "\\gap50 ", modelpath, "\\", mfiler))`. I run R from RStudio, but do not have admin rights for neither of the two. If I run `shell("whoami")` I get my username back.